# How to sum the multiplied columns from subquery in linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to multiply columns from a table and using subquery i have tried to sum the multiplied columns

```
select B.ID , sum(B) from (
select distinct A.Id, 
A.Savings * A.Spent as B,
from A group by A.id ) B
group by B.ID
```

How can i convert this sql query to linq.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is wrong at this point:

```
A.Savings * A.Spent as B,
from A group by A.id
```

a coma before the from clause will error the query out. Try the below:

```
SELECT
B.ID,
SUM(Total) AS TOTAL
FROM 
(SELECT
 A.Savings * A.Spent as Total
 From A
 Group by A.ID)
Group by B.ID
```

Your query is right, you may just need to check in future.

Comment: Question is How can i convert this sql query to linq.